# Change the visual studio solution file from 2013 to 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I have a project that I made in Visual Studio 2010 earlier before Visual Studio 2013 came out.

After visual studio 2013 come out, I uninstalled Visual Studio 2010 and opened the project in Visual Studio 2013.

I found that in Visual Studio 2013, it doesn't support creation of a setup MSI file with just a couple of click and setting, so i decided to install Visual Studio 2010 again in my computer.

Then I opened the project in Visual Studio 2010 but once I open the file with VS2010, an error says it cannot be opened because the project was from newer version of visual studio.

How can I solve this?  Thanks

Comment: install Visual Studio 2010 Update/SP 3 or higher. It makes Visual Studio 2010 solutions compatible with 2012 which are the same in 2013. Then you will be able to open it without an issue.

Comment: Maybe you can change the files back to 2010? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20486230/how-to-convert-visual-studios-2013-project-to-visual-studios-2010

Answer (score 3):

The thing is that after VS2012 it does not support MSI files so that it will give you Unsupported error..

The alternative for making set up file is using Top shelf which provides same functionality u needed so implement it and remove setup files then it will easily run on VS2013.

http://topshelf-project.com/

https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf

AND FOR UR QUERY :-

```
Just open the solution in a text editor in the second line you can find

Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00

change the version to 11.00 and save it.

Try to open the solution and it works.
```

Comment: what is that link for sir?

And for the query, how do i change the version of the solution file?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new visual studio 2010 solution and add the files/projects manually.
Also use a versioning system (e.g. svn) to prevent this from happening in the future again.

Comment: is there any way to convert back the solution file to 2010?

Comment: I guess you could open the vcxproj in an editor and reset the ToolsVersion and PlatformToolset. But I do not know if it would break something.

Comment: what if I have a big native c++ solution that has about 150 project each project has ...will I add it one by one? this is a very bad solution.

Comment: The OP did not mention a solution with 150 projects. I rather copy a small post-it with a pencil, then using the printing press of a national telegraph. A solution is not necessary bad, because it does not fit a specific case.