# How to convert Visual Studios 2013 project to Visual Studios 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I have a project in **Microsoft Visual Studios 2013** and I want to open it in **Microsoft Visual Studios 2010**. Is there any easy way? or Do I have to create a new project in 2010 and add all files from 2013 project?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Open you solution file in notepad. Make 1 change, as stated in [Converting VS2012 Solution to VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143383/converting-vs2012-solution-to-vs2010/13458225#13458225):

> Replace "# Visual Studio 2013" with "# Visual Studio 2010" (without
>   quotes.)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ef97fa9c-b89b-4a89-8bda-03457dff9c61/how-to-downgrade-from-visual-studio-2012-project-to-vs-2010

[How to downgrade from Visual Studio 2012 project to Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507901/how-to-downgrade-from-visual-studio-2012-project-to-visual-studio-2008)

Comment: "Replace "# Visual Studio 2013" with "# Visual Studio 2010" (without quotes.)" is one change, what's the other one?

Comment: "Format Version 12.00" with "Format Version 11.00" (without quotes.) The Version 12.00 is for VS 2012.I'm not sure about VS 2013..

Comment: Format Version for 2013 is 12.00

Comment: Please take a look at reference link..and also this https://vsprojectconverter.codeplex.com/

Comment: Are we assuming that the 2013 project was using .Net 4.0? Do we need to check that as well?

Answer (score 8):

I had some issues that were resolved by a combination of things. In my case I was converting a VB 2013 project to 2010. I solved it by:

Open the solution file in notepad (.sln)
Change these lines:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
- Visual Studio 2013

To:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00
- Visual Studio 2010

I also had to update the references. I had the issue that it give an error every time I went to view designer. In my case it was:

- Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library -> Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library -> Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library
- Reassign the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3

Answer (score 4):

open the solution file with notepad and editing like

Format Version 12.00===>  Format Version 11.00

## Visual Studio 2013===>  # Visual Studio 2010

is also working

Answer (score 0):

I changed ToolsVersion="12.0" to ToolsVersion="4.0" in my .csproj file and .csproj.user file, I hope it helps someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

(credit to @PandiyanT and @talmok)

This worked for me: open the solution(.sln) file with Notepad and change right values to left values in this way :

- `Format Version 12.00`   to    `Format Version 11.00`
- `Visual Studio 2013`   to   `# Visual Studio 2010`

and then open visual C# project file with notepad and change right value to left value in this way :

- `ToolsVersion="12.0"`   to   `ToolsVersion="4.0"`

Answer (score 0):

For **2015** to **2010** Premium use these lines in the .sln file.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.0
# Visual Studio 11
VisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to change to these 2 lines. Changed from 12 to 11. And changed from 4.5 on the framework to 4.0 on the project file .csproj

```
<Project ToolsVersion="11.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```