# Linking with static libraries built in previous versions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, ide

Target OS: Windows DS7 64 Bit;

Our team is Using VS2010 for a C++ Framework development. We statically link with another Custom framework which is Using VS2010 as IDE. Our goal is to deliver static libs and dlls for clients which are using VS2005 or VS2010. Basically, we provide full functionality DLLs, but also a custom API.

Questions:

1. Is it possible that we update our IDE to VS2015 and keep linking to VS2010 deliverable from our "supplier"?
2. For our customers now:  Is it possible that we build for all requested VS IDE versions by keeping only the Toolset (target framework) from VS 2010/2005 etc.  and Uninstalling previous versions of MS VS from the Build Machines?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a Visual Studio 2015 C++ project compatible with Visual Studio 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29515566/how-do-i-make-a-visual-studio-2015-c-project-compatible-with-visual-studio-201)

Comment: With two and half major C++ language revisions, having no major unsolvable linker problems is a pretty unlikely outcome.  You should likewise not destroy older VS versions, your customer did not necessarily update.

Comment: "Uninstalling previous versions of MS VS from the Build Machines" -- I believe that's where the older toolsets come from.

Comment: Hi Dan, thank you for your answer! By Un-installing previous versions  I meant only keeping some sort of standalone set needed for Compiling/Linking for older VS versions like eg. for VS2005, C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets'
In there you copy the two setting files:
    'Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.v80.props'
    'Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.v80.targets'