# How to convert vs2013 to 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, converters

I need to convert a project from "Visual Studio Express 2013" to "Visual C# Express 2010". Do I need to download a converter to do this or is there an other way?

Comment: Have you tried it? What error messages does it dive (if any)? I think that the structure of VS2010, VS2012 and VS2013 projects files should be the same and should work in any version. There are also a few other questions similar to yours on this site, have you looked at any of those?

Answer (score 1):

Following the answer here: [How to convert Visual Studios 2013 project to Visual Studios 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20486230/how-to-convert-visual-studios-2013-project-to-visual-studios-2010)

> Replace "# Visual Studio 2013" with "# Visual Studio 2010" (without quotes.)

OR

> Replace  Format Version 12.00 with Format Version 11.00

The first option is more acceptable.