# Compiling a .net-free with Visual Studio Express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm getting started with Visual Studio 2010 Express. A simple "Hello world" program (with a window and a command button) is being compiled with .net assembles, so it will require a .net to run.

Is there a way to set up Visual Studio to compile the code natively **without** using .net dependencies? Just a plain executable without .net dependencies.

Comment: Only if you code it natively with C or C++, not with .NET

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a .Net application, you're going to need the .Net Framework to run the program. If you don't want to use the .Net Framework then you are creating the wrong type of application. If you're trying to create a C++ application, you need to use the C++ templates.

Comment: I go `File > New Project > Win32 > Win32 Project`. It compiles with .net assembles...

Comment: Please upload your project some place where I can get it. You've got to be doing something wrong.

Comment: You can find my example [here](http://downloads.kenhostusa.com/downloads/Win32-Without-Dot-Net-Assemblies.zip).

Comment: Yours: `VisualStudioVersion = 12.0.21005.1`. Mine is 2010 Express. Won't open it

Comment: Well, you can [download](https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/profile/review?download=true&family=VisualStudioExpressWindows&release=VisualStudio2013Upd4&type=iso&slcid=0x409&context=eyJwZSI6MSwicGMiOjEsImljIjoxLCJhbyI6MSwiYW0iOjAsIm9wIjpudWxsLCJhZCI6bnVsbCwiZmEiOjAsImF1IjpudWxsLCJjdiI6MTA5ODY2NzQzMiwiZnMiOjAsInN1IjowLCJlciI6MX01) it for free, or you can just use a text editor to see the file. They are plain text files. I don't have the older versions of Visual Studio anymore.

Comment: Also, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20486230/how-to-convert-visual-studios-2013-project-to-visual-studios-2010).